# Flutter app Minimized and Going another app and back to App again app restart some time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

In My app i going to one page  and Minimize app using device buttons and going to another app (put in to recent app) came back to flutter app some time app restarting, I already using  AppLifecycleState for the check state  also there state working fine after going to Minimized app state  going to inactive  & paused  also when back to resumed method also called. AppLifecycleState also working fine in debug mode, any one have solution for this issue

Comment: It also happens to me, have you solved it?

Comment: Same thing. I'll post when I find a solution.

Comment: Confirmed on my side, as additional info I'm using GetX as state management

Comment: I'm having this issue. Has anyone resolved it yet?